# Android - java: Bluetooth connection event on broadcastReceiver not triggered

Tags: java, android

I've to handle the event triggered by the connection of my BluetoothAdapter to a new device. I've tried with this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver bluetoothConnectionStateListener = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1);
        switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED:
                Log.i("BLE info", "Bluetooth connected");
                connectedDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                setConnectedLayout();
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                Log.i("BLE info", "Bluetooth disconnected");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

For the registration:

```
registerReceiver(bluetoothConnectionStateListener, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));
```

But the onReceive() method is never called.
(Note: the connection happens in a separated Thread)

What's wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You are giving wrong IntentFilter. BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED broadcast when the state of the local Bluetooth adapter has been changed l(like  STATE_OFF, STATE_TURNING_ON, STATE_ON, STATE_TURNING_OFF). Please read the [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED).

Comment: if you want the Broadcast for BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED then add `android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED` in your Manifest->application->intent-filter.

Comment: @SalmanNaseem Thanks! So I have to pass ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED to the IntentFilter?